# Differences between Assumed Density Filtering vs Variational Inference

Tags: variational-bayes, variational-inference

I am new to the concept of Assumed Density Filtering (ADF) but I think that it is very similar to Variational Inference (VI). In VI, we estimate a intractable posterior distribution (p) by finding a approximate distribution (q) that is closest to the distribution of interest i.e. minimizing the KL divergence KL(q || p). Isn't this the same as what we have in ADF?

Please enlighten me if I seem to be missing the nuances in the two methods. Are there any pros and cons of the two methods? References would be helpful.